# rails webmock in development mode breaks app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, webmock

I try to mock the twitter api, therefore I am using webmock in the following way. In an initializer I do save a http response with page = 'curl - is twitterurl with json dataresponse' then I do stub_request(:get, %r|friends/list|).to_return(page)

it is actually working unfortunately my controller in which i make the api call gets stuck and my server (thin) is stuck.
Help is appreciated,
Phil

Comment: You need to provide the error please... if you still have the issue 